# change user-agent into google bot in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I need to change the user agent to Googlebot in java

here is my code-

```
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src/main/resources/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("user-agent= Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

but in the browser, I am only visible custom agent by default in Chrome

can I am getting somd good solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

in python you can change user-agent like this:

```py
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setUserAgentOverride",{"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html"})
```

in java,you can refer to the following:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setUserAgentOverride